# What is the plural of "staff"?

Tags: grammatical-number

I am a teacher and we are in doubt if the plural form of *staff* is *staffs*. We have been debating on this topic.

Comment: Dictionary.com says staffs exists: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/staffs
Depends on the meaning you're talking about, though.

Comment: See  OALD staff, grammar point   http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/staff_1?q=staff

Answer (score 11):

*Staffs*, when you're talking about the staff of Office A and the staff of Office B.

If you are talking about the kind of staff that Gandalf carries, the plural is *staves*, which is a word I've always liked.

Comment: Also in music, the plural of staff is staves. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=music+staves+and+notes&sa=X&biw=1132&bih=772&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&ved=0CCAQsARqFQoTCNaxmam3_cYCFcsXLAodydYPGg

Comment: Personally, I would rather use the singular form *staff* in the first context. "The staff of offices A and B are entitled to take half a day off preceding a bank holiday" sounds much more natural to me. In fact, if you used "staffs" in this context, I wager that most people would just consider it a typo or poor grammar. I would use "staffs" as a plural of the sort of staff that Gandalf carries in preference to "staves" unless I was going for literary effect.

Comment: Words that are almost always singular can become plural if you talk about varieties. Water, as a non-count noun, is singular until we talk about varieties of water: "In Mexico, where they told us not to drink the water, the connoisseur can find many delicious bottled waters to sip during lazy afternoons at a table in a sidewalk café. My favorite is Topo Chico." Then there's the expression, "Still waters run deep." With those precedents it's easy to imagine the staffs of Stripling-Blake Lumber and Brick House Construction meeting for a game of softball, each staff comprising a team.

Comment: Although there seems some dispute on the plural of *quarterstaff*, with some sources preferring *quarterstaves* (Merriam-Webster, Collins online) and others also allowing *quarterstaffs* (Wikipedia, Wiktionary, Dictionary.com).

Answer (score 9):

"Staff" as a collective noun meaning a body of people takes either a ***singular*** or **plural** verb depends on whether you're thinking of the body as a unit:

> The *staff* ***is*** unanimously opposed to the dean's recommendation.

or as multiple individuals

> All the *staff* **were** shocked by the dean's recommendation.

The plural of "staff" is "staffs," and when you talk about staffs, you're talking about separate bodies of people, which, of course, requires a plural verb:

> The *staffs* of both colleges **were** supportive of the joint program.

Comment: The rat says sooth. Excellent answer.

Comment: Good answer. But as someone has commented below one could just as easily say *the staff of both colleges*. I think I would only use *staffs* if I was wanting to draw attention to their separate collective status  e.g. *the different languages spoken by the two companies' staffs made the merger between the French company and its German competitor especially troublesome*.

Answer (score -2):

My recollection, which is not as reliable as it used to be, is that "staffs" is always plural for "staff" in British English (two staff members are two staffs), and most American English speakers use "staff" for both singular and plural. However, I sometimes hear the word "staffers" coming out of WDC news stories. The only time I seem to hear "staffs" as plural of "staff" is in British English.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).